# How to add two text rows to one and keep other rows same as before pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to add two text rows to one and keep other rows same as before pandas
How to do that by pandas?

original dataframe:

```
   textA  TextB
0       a        zz
1       bbb        zzzzz
2       ccc        zzz
```

desired output is:

```
   textA  TextB
0       a bbb       zz
1       bbb        zzzzz
2       ccc        zzz
```

> i mean i just add two row text to specific row and other rows keep
> original values

Comment: `df.loc[0, 'textA'] += ' ' + df.loc[1, 'textA']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean by something like:

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'textA'] += ' ' + df.loc[1, 'textA']
>>> df
   textA  TextB
0  a bbb     zz
1    bbb  zzzzz
2    ccc    zzz
>>>
```